# Dont understand difference between these two programs, one is if-else second one is if-else-if

Tags: java

Hello i got code from my book about if-else-if statements here is the code

```
{
    int mesec = 4; // April
    String season;

    if(mesec==12 || mesec==1 || mesec==2)
        season= "winter";
    else if (mesec==3 || mesec==4 || mesec==5)
        season= "spring";
    else if (mesec==6 || mesec==7 || mesec==8)
        season= "summer";
    else if (mesec ==9 || mesec ==10 || mesec ==11)
        season= "autumn";
    else
        season = "wrong month";

    System.out.println("When it is April, it is "+season);
}
```

This code works perfectly when i use if-else-if statement, but when i try to use only if-else

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int mesec = 4; // April
    String season;

    if(mesec==12 || mesec==1 || mesec==2)
        season= "winter";
    if (mesec==3 || mesec==4 || mesec==5)
        season= "spring";
    if (mesec==6 || mesec==7 || mesec==8)
        season= "summer";
    if (mesec ==9 || mesec ==10 || mesec ==11)
        season= "autumn";
    else
        season = "wrong month";

    System.out.println("When it is April, it is "+season);
}
```

i always got wrong output which is "When it is April, it is wrong month"

When we use if-else-if variable season save which season it is,
but when we use only if-else it save only season from else statement ? can anyone explane my what is the problem ?

Comment: Add {} chars, and it may become clearer...

Comment: In the first one, the final `else` stands for all the preceding `if` and `elseif` , in the second one, it stands only for the last `if` n meaning that your code will probably pass in another `if` AND finally in this `else` , explaining why you got this result. If you test the second one with a month between 9 and 11, it will work as expected... but the first one is the best one of both. You could also do it with `<` and `>`comparisons

Comment: This is a great example of a time when you should just use a debugger to see what's going on.  Also, you shouldn't be tagging a bunch of unrelated languages.

Comment: @Miljan Rakita are you satisfied with the 6 answers? why ask a question and run away when others are trying to help you?

Comment: Thank you Bartudude :) I understand it now :)

Comment: As an asside, I think you should read [braceless-if-considered-harmful](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/) about not using these if statements without `{` `}`

Comment: In first case the else condition will be executed only if the other 4 conditions were not satisfied whereas in the second case the else is tied only to the 4th if condition.

Answer (score 5):

The `else` statement in the second program only applies to the last `if`:

```
if (mesec ==9 || mesec ==10 || mesec ==11)
```

So it will only work the way you expect if the month is 9, 10, or 11.

Answer (score 3):

> can anyone explane my what is the problem ?

By saying:

```
if (mesec ==9 || mesec ==10 || mesec ==11)
    season= "autumn";
else
    season = "wrong month";
```

you overwrite `season`, i.e. if `mesec` was `4` earlier, then `season` was `spring`, but the above condition does evaluate to `false` thereby setting `season` to `wrong month`.

Answer (score 2):

you get wrong answer because in last case

```
if (mesec ==9 || mesec ==10 || mesec ==11)
    season= "autumn"; // this will evaluate false as mesec=4
else
    season = "wrong month"; // So this will be executed and hence wrong month
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine till the following Block:

```
if (mesec==3 || mesec==4 || mesec==5)
        season= "spring";
```

and as it is again checking with the remaining following 2 conditions:

```
 if (mesec==6 || mesec==7 || mesec==8)
        season= "summer";
    if (mesec ==9 || mesec ==10 || mesec ==11)
        season= "autumn";
```

and as above condition `Fails` it executes `Last` else block

```
 else
        season = "wrong month";
```

which sets your `season` variable to `wrong month`

Answer (score 1):

In the secnd case all the if statement will be executed. Hence the output. When it is April, it is wrong month". Becuase last if will not match, it will go to else part.

Answer (score 1):

Added comments to your code so you can follow the logic easier; it should be clear now that each if statement is an independent logic branch, whereas the version with elseif is a single logic statement.

```
            int mesec = 4; // April
            string season;

            //mesec doesn't meet this condition
            if (mesec == 12 || mesec == 1 || mesec == 2)
            {
                season = "winter";
            }

            //mesec does meet this condition
            if (mesec==3 || mesec==4 || mesec==5)
            {   
                season= "spring";
            }

            //mesec doesn't meet this condition
            if (mesec==6 || mesec==7 || mesec==8)
            {
                season= "summer";
            }

            //mesec doesn't meet this condition
            if (mesec == 9 || mesec == 10 || mesec == 11)
            {
                season = "autumn";
            }
            else //since mesec doesn't meet the if condition, it comes in here.
            {
                season = "wrong month";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the `else` only applies to the last `if`. But here's why.

Java doesn't have an `if-else-if-else` construct — just `if-else`. When you type:

```
if (condA) {
    doA();
} else if (condB) {
    doB();
} else if (condC) {
    doC();
} else {
    doDefault();
}
```

... you're *really* typing:

```
if (condA) {
    doA();
} else {
    if (condB) {
        doB();
    } else {
        if (condC) {
            doC();
        } else {
            doDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

This works because the `else`'s can either be a block (surrounded by curly braces) or a statement — including an `if-else` statement. For instance, in the above example, the `if(condB)` has an `else` that uses a statement, not a block. That statement is an `if-else` statement: `if (condC) { ... } else { ... }`.

On the other hand, without the "else if" bits, you have this:

```
if (condA) {
    doA();
} // no else

// New statement
if (condB) {
    doB();
} // no else

// New statement
if (condC) {
    doC();
} else {
    doDefault();
}
```